# How to hide text of \mainline in Chess Diagram?

Tags: chess, chessboard, skak

I would like to remove the text produced by the \mainline but not the diagram.

```
    \documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{skak}
    \usepackage{chessboard} 
    \def\mainlinestyle{\bfseries}
    \def\variationstyle{}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \newgame

    \styleA

    \mainline{1.g4 e5 2.f3 Qh4} 

    \chessboard
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the quickest game. :-)

Comment: It's Called Grob's Attack. An unusual opening in Chess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use \hidemoves.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{skak}
    \usepackage{chessboard}
    \def\mainlinestyle{\bfseries}
    \def\variationstyle{}

    \begin{document}
    \newgame

    \styleA

    \hidemoves{1.g4 e5 2.f3 Qh4}
    \chessboard
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Preamble:- \usepackage{xskak,chessboard}  \makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{} 
\makeatother

Comment: Don't  ask new questions like this in a comment, create a new question instead.

Comment: Okay Ulrike Fischer, I thought its a continuation of the above.

Comment: Even if it is a continuation: this here is a question/answer site, not a discussion forum; the answers are not only for you -- other should be able to use them too, so one should avoid to extend or add questions in comments.